# How can I disable shift+enter in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver, line-breaks

So I'm curious how to disable the 'code-view' 'shift+enter' 'line break' shortcut in Dreamweaver. All I can find on the internet is 'why would you want to do that?' - so I can tell you ahead of time that won't be helpful to me in any way.

To answer the question however, because I know the first thing to run through everyone's head is 'why Does he want to do that' is a simple one; So I can parenthesis+linebreak+openbracket. If you follow the keystrokes, you'll note that if I hold shift across the whole thing ( which is required for the first and last ) - that I will end up with 
's all over the place. This is becoming quite the annoyance and everyone on the internet has useless responses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I can bump this...

Comment: Dammit, I'm having this problem too. Everyone out there is like "wait, why don't you like <br/>?" or "mine inserts <br>, I think you have a different doctype"

Comment: This is off topic for SO, I'm voting to migrate it to SU, but for the record its edit>keyboard shortcuts, then click the "duplicate set" at the top (since you can't modify the default one), and under menu commands, it's Insert>HTML>Special Characters>Linebreak.

Comment: Worked like a charm bud, not sure why you didn't add this as an answer. Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by @Carson Myers in the comments following my question:

To remove the Shift+Enter Keyboard Shortcut in Dreamweaver that inserts an HTML Line Feed, follow these steps:

In Dreamweaver;
 Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...

From the edit screen;
 Click the 'Duplicate Set' button, and name your new set something relative to your reasoning for making the change, I went with 'Dreamweaver PHP Development', as it was in this environment that I encountered the necessity to make this change.

In your newly generated keyboard shortcut set, find the shortcut for a Linebreak in the following sub-'folder':
Insert > HTML > Special Characters > Linebreak

Once you have located this 'key', remove the 'Shift+Enter' shortcut from its list of shortcuts, and add another one if you feel the necessity.

Following these steps removes the automatic insertion of an HTML Linebreak when using Shift+Enter. In my scenario, this allowed me to type the following sequence; '()\n{\n}' without having to release the shift button.

Thanks to @Carson Myers for the information.